# Знаки препинания в предложении: правильно ли расставлены?

Tags: пунктуация

Будьте добры, поселите в общежитие по адресу: Улица Ленина, 4, -за наличный расчет.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что правильным будет: Будьте добры, поселите  за наличный расчет (желательно указать кого именно) по адресу: ул. Ленина, 4.  Или "Будьте добры, поселите ... Расчет наличными."